# Scala - understand class definition with Bounds

Tags: scala, class, templates, operators

I am learning Scala and I've seen some classes constructed with a template:

Like:

```
class Name[+S <: State](val name: String)


class User[S <: State] {
  def state(implicit n: Name[S]): String = n.name
}
```

What means here `<:` and `+S` ?

And the sate function doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few keywords that might be useful:

For `<:` and `>:`, check out upper and lower type bounds: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html#bounds

For `S+` and `S-`, covariant and contravariant types: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html#variance

To understand what the state function is doing, check out how implicit parameters work: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html